# Case when function in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Im not sure what is the issue with this code. I need number to be changed based on Entity field

````
select CASE WHEN :P64_ENTITY = 'India' THEN 1
WHEN :P64_ENTITY = 'China' THEN 2
WHEN :P64_ENTITY = 'Japan' THEN 3
 else 0 END;```
````

Comment: What is the code doing/ not doing that you want it to stop/ start doing?  Are you sure that `:P64_ENTITY` is populated and has the value you expect it to have?

Comment: If you are using on change event for something, maybe you need to send the value to the session before to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is your item :P64_ENTITY is empty in value property.